# Why can't I see any change in used memory when I run my program?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have written a program to allocate some memory as given by cmd line argument. It creates an array to consume some amount of memory, and it goes through the array for 30 seconds.

When I run it, I cant see any change in memory usage(edit: I didnt mean gradual change of memory usage, the problem was no memory was initialized due to a missing line of code) of the program. I have tried this both in Windows using Task Manager and in Linux with free() utility.

I am a beginner in C so I am afraid that I might be missing something basic. I thank you for your time to look into this and appreciate your help.

Edit: I for some reason deleted what C was meant to be. Feeling stupid now.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])                  //for getting cmd line arg of size in MB
{   int d=atoi(argv[1]), b=0, c=0, i=0;           //store the value into an integer
    b=d*1024*1024;                                //convert MB to B
    /*initially missing line below, this fixes the original issue*/
    c=b/4;                                        //int being 4 bytes each elements will be 1/4th of total B
    /*missing line ends*/
    printf("value passed to array size\n- %d",b); //show total size to allocate in B
    
    int *num = (int *)malloc(b);                  //allocating b bytes
    
    time_t sec = 30;                              //setting timer to 30secand then looping for said time
    time_t startT=time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) - startT < sec)
    {
        for(i=0;i<c;i++)                          //going through each entry in the array and assigning it its position as value
            {
                num[i]=i;
            }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is it intended that `num[i]=i;` won't be executed because `c=0`?

Comment: `for(i=0;i<c;i++)` - look at your code and ask yourself what the value of `c` is when this loop is reached. And before you "fix" it by using `b` instead, your code will invoke UB if you do so because the `malloc` was done with a byte count; not an element count.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks for catching my blunder with c. Its fixed now.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you for pointing it out, my bad.

Comment: Also, "I cant see any change in memory usage of the program.", almost immediately your program allocates the only dynamic memory it will ever acquire, a `d`-megabytes sized chunk. After that, it never acquires any further. So, unless you somehow caught your program between the start of `main` and the invoke of `malloc` (realistically only doable as-is if running inside a debugger), you'll see *no* changes in memory footprint whatsoever. If you're expecting a memory run-up, this code won't do it. It has *one* allocation, and it's done before the wait loop is ever reached.

Comment: @WhozCraig But I do see it after the fix, as its looping for 30 seconds or so, the memory is being constantly manipulated no?

Comment: Let me say that again: You said, *"When I run it, I cant see any change in memory usage of the program."* - that's because your program doesn't change anything regarding amount of memory used after that single initial allocation. Again, *look at your code*. What are you expecting this to do, creep up in memory *consumption* ? The code doesn't do that, so neither will your program. With everything "fixed" this just repeatedly writes to an already-allocated block of memory. There is no change in footprint, so no change in said-same will be conveyed by any monitoring tools.

Comment: @0x13 writing to memory does not allocate it

Comment: @WhozCraig There was a miscommunication, I only meant the initial allocation, I did not mean a gradual change. The initial allocation did not happen because there was, c=0, and was missing the line c=b/4.

Comment: @0___________ "writing to memory does not allocate it" This is not quite true (surprise I know). That's because allocating memory doesn't really allocate memory (oh my, another surprise). Look up "optimistic memory allocation".

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Interesting in your opinion there is only one implementation in the world - do you think that uC implementations use optimistic memory allocation? You talk about one of many possible implementations. In c standard writing is not allocating anything.

Comment: @WhozCraig "What are you expecting this to do, creep up in memory consumption ?" That's *exactly* what should happen when the typo is fixed. Perhaps it will happen too fast to see, but if you insert some delays in the loop, you will see it with your naked eyes,

Comment: @0___________ I quote, "I have tried this both in Windows using Task Manager and in Linux with free() utility." (end of quote). **These** implementations use optimistic memory allocation. Thus, "writing to memory does not allocate it" is simply not true, because **some** implementations, and **all** implementations this question is concerned with, use optimistic memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

To see increased memory consumption increase you allocate some memory every iteration:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])           
{   
    size_t size = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("value passed to array size %zu\n", size); 
    
    int *num = NULL;
    
    time_t sec = 30;                             
    time_t startT=time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) - startT < sec)
    {
        int *tmp = realloc(num, size * 1024 *1024);
        if(!tmp) 
        {
            free(num);
            break;
        }
        num = tmp;
        for(size_t i=0; i< size * 1024 *1024 / sizeof(*num);i++)                         
        {
            num[i]=i;
        }
        size *= 2;
    }
    
}
```